# NavigationBar not appearing

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

I've got a Collection view controller linked to my navigation controller. In the storyboard the navigation bar appears and disappears at random but it's still in the hierarchy. When I switch back to this view however the navigationBar disappears.

I tried this but it doesn't do anything -

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)
```

**-Screenshot of storyboard**[image]

I'm using Swift 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was changing view incorrectly. I used "present modally" instead of "show". Once I corrected the segue the navigation bar now appears and I can use back gestures.

[Apple's webpage on using Navigation Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have constraints set on the collection view? Make sure it is pinned to the top of the view so it is always under the navigation bar (or if you want it to fill up the whole screen, set the constraints to 0 on all sides)

Comment: I don't have any constraints set on it yet but the navigation bar does show when the view initially loads. It's just when you return to the view that it disappears

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of it? Are you doing anything to the navigation bar when the view loads?

Comment: I added a barButton and I use that for SWRevealViewController but nothing other than that. The nav bar is either there when the view loads and then gone when I return to the view, it doesn't leave a blank space where it should be either. In the storyboard the nav controller adds the nav bar

Comment: Your initial view did have the navigation bar because it was embedded in a navigation controller from a previous hierarchy.

The segue from your SWRevealViewController to that view again probably does not have a navigation controller. When you show (segue into) the view again from SWRevealViewController, embed that segue in a navigation controller.

Post your storyboard layout (if you are using that) and it should be clear

Comment: added a screenshot of my storyboard

Comment: I've tried going to the navigation controller instead of directly to the collectionView, the navigationBar now appears but the menu buttons don't function. If I go to the SWRevealViewController VC it works fine, but I've got other views that need to go back and forth so this won't be a full solution

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```